# Populate new data into an imported component template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a `Projects Module` which contains the `Projects List` component. The `Project List` component shows a list of **all projects by all users**.

Now I have a `Dashboard Module` which contains a `User Dashboard` component. The `User Dashboard` components **should show a list of projects for that user only.**

Now I have exported the `Project List` component and have imported it in the `Dashboard Module` and added the template selector in the `User Dashboard` component template.

**Export Project List Component:**

```
 exports: [ProjectListComponent]
```

**Import in Dashboard Module:**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {DashboardComponent} from './components/dashboard.component';
import {ProjectModule} from "../projects/project.module";

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule,
     ProjectModule
 ],
 declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule {
}
```

**Add in User Dashboard Template:**

```
<project-list></project-list>
```

The above works and it displays the template of `project-list` in the `User Dashboard` component.

**Issues:**

Is it possible to populate the `<project-list></project-list>` with new data **(i.e only that users projects and NOT all users projects)**

Is this even possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not sure i got what you need, could you explain more please

Comment: @Nour Basically I wanna reuse a components template in another module and populate new data into it. Does that make sense?

Comment: If i understand you, you can create shared module that contains shared components and use these component whenever you need.

Comment: Maybe you can use content projection with `ng-content`. There are many tutorials on the subject if you search for it. Unfortunately the official documentation still doesn't mention this topic.

Comment: Why not define an `input`?

Comment: @karthikaruna Thats a good idea! Would it effect the `proposal-list` component when its being used on its own? Does this make sense?

Comment: If you use `project-list` as a component that just displays whatever you pass in as input, things should be fine.

Comment: @karthikaruna okay. There are 2 ways the data is being passed into it. 1) Data passed as `input`when `project-list` is embedded within another component. 2) Data is passed from the `project service` when the `project-list` is accessed via a `route` change.

Comment: No problem. Just check if input is `undefined`. If so, set the data from route to that variable. It should work fine, since the same variable is used in `*ngFor`, either way.

Comment: @Skywalker, got it?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProjectList {
    @Input() projectListData;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.projectListData = this.projectListData ? this.projectListData : this.route.snapshot.data['projectListData']
    }
}
```

When you don't pass data to input (`<project-list></project-list>`), `projectListData` will be `undefined`. So the route data is assigned to `projectListData`.

Else (`<project-list [projectListData]="projectListData"></project-list>`), the data you passed as input will be used.

In the template,

```
<tr *ngFor="let project of projectListData">
    ...
</tr>
```